# Can I address my professors by their first name?

Tags: graduate-school, professorship, undergraduate

A couple of my professors always signs off on their emails with their first name only, such as, "best, Simon".

Does this mean that I could write my emails to them with, "Dear Simon" or "Hi Simon" ...and also say to him in person "good morning, Simon"?

Or, should I stick with "Professor "?

Should I ask for permission, e.g., "can I call you Simon?" ?

(Not sure whether age matters, but both of these professors are very young...)

Thanks,

Comment: You haven't said anything about your relationship with these professors, but depending on the extent of that relationship we've covered this from many angles already:

Comment: If you are not sure, ask. Otherwise, I generally stick to calling people whatever they choose to call themselves in the last mail. So if he signed with "Best, Simon" I would address him as Simon.

Comment: [Should I call my adviser by her first name?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/27723/), [Is it acceptable for me (an undergrad) to call professors and other research professionals by their first names?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/25758/), [At what point can I call my professor by their first names?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/45323/)

Comment: I have closed this as "unclear what you're asking" in the meantime because you haven't specified anything about your relationship with these professors. (Are you a student in their classes? a research student in their department? are they your advisors? something else?)

Comment: Regardless of the relationship, though, I'm pretty sure [this answer](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/27726/11365) also answers your question :)