# Addressing professors with their first name only

Tags: mathematics, postdocs, professorship, email, correspondence

I am going to apply for a postdoc call and I have commenced exchanging emails with a professor. In his first reply to my initial email he addressed me with my first name (Dear (my first name)). In my second email I address him as

> Dear Professor (His first name only)

and his reply on my second email was

> Dear Colleague.

Now I do not know whether I can address him with his first name without using the word "professor"?

Comment: probable duplicate of https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/84410/75368

Comment: In the US, addressing a professor as "Professor Tony" (their first name) is extremely weird. I suggest you keep it formal until you meet them personally.

Comment: @Buffy Many Thanks for informing me about the above links, they are extremely useful. I am sorry for not searching a lot and mentioning duplicated question.

Comment: A bit of warning. While it isn't especially polite or sensible, addressing those perceived as "underlings" by their first name is pretty common. But people who do that may not appreciate a symmetric addressing _by_ those they consider underlings. Hence, I suggest formality until you have explicit permission. "Professor Smythe" (family name) is always safe. "Professor Tony" or "Tony" can be read (probably unfairly) as presumptuous. If you weren't seeking something from them it would probably not matter. But here, it might.  Note that many people _never_ address their parents by first name.

Comment: In formal correspondence, including during the application process for a position, address faculty in emails with "Dear Professor [Last Name]." Even if they sign an email with their first name use Professor [Last Name]. Only use their first name if they explicitly tell you to use their first name.